# Google Sheets: How do I combine a column of URLs and a column of text into one?

Tags: google-sheets

How do I combine two separate columns of **Titles** and **Webpages** into one?

The list is very long so I can't do it one by one. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Do you want to just append the content of both columns (including the format) or perform some  operation with the content?

Comment: I just wanted to create a link with a user friendly name, the post below solved it! So simple. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you want is:

```
=hyperlink(B1,A1)
```

This preserves the link as in B1 but gives it the friendly name as in A1.